# Is there a fieldset disable alternative?

Tags: html, fieldset

I really enjoy the disabling of entire fieldsets, it's quick and simple. While testing my code in the 5 major browsers, I realized that Safari and IE (sort of) do not support disabling entire field sets. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_fieldset_disabled.asp

Is there an alternative to this fieldset attribute? Maybe a way to disable all fields within a fieldset one by one? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: IE8 and IE9 *should* support disabling fieldsets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript or jQuery to disable the inputs inside the fieldset.

jQuery Example (put this at the bottom of your page):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("fieldset").find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
</script>
```

or if you want to disable a single class or id you can do:

```
$(".className").find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#elementId").find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

To use with a radio button you can do something like this:

```
$("#radioButtonTrue").on("click", function () {
    $("fieldset").find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
$("#radioButtonFalse").on("click", function () {
    $("fieldset").find("input").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: I haven't used much jQuery...so how can I call this from an on change? Right now I have a radio button that calls `onchange="greyOut(this.value)"`. How can I call the jQuery function instead?

Inside greyOut I run `document.getElementsByName('myFieldSet')[0].disabled=true;`

Comment: I edited my answer. I forgot to select the inputs in the fieldset the first time.